# Using d3.js in Angular2/Node/Express/MongoDB App

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, d3.js

I'm trying to bring d3.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) into my project and I get a `ZoneAwareError` on page load. I have ran `npm install d3 --save` and everything got brought in just fine. I followed the documentation on how to import it into my Angular2 Component but receive the below error on page load:

I should also note that all intellisense for d3 is showing up in Web Storm just fine.

```
ZoneAwareError
  (anonymous function)  
  ZoneDelegate.invoke   
  Zone.run  
  (anonymous function)  
  ZoneDelegate.invokeTask   
  Zone.runTask  
  drainMicroTaskQueue   
  ZoneTask.invoke
```

Component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'map-component',
  templateUrl: '/mlbstats.map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['mlbstats.map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      d3.select('p');  
  }
}
```

If I comment out the line `d3.select('p');` the page loads fine. Is there an extra step that needs to be completed for this to work? What exactly does the `ZoneAwareError` translate to? I can't get a better error message so I'm not sure what is causing this. If I use the Chrome dev tools (opposed to the web storm dev tools) I get the below error:

(SystemJS) Unexpected token <↵  SyntaxError: Unexpected token <↵        at eval ()↵      at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/../public/pages/PortfolioComponent/MLBStats/MapComponent/mlbstats.map.component.js:15:10)↵        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/../public/pages/PortfolioComponent/MLBStats/MapComponent/mlbstats.map.component.js:38:4)↵        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/../public/pages/PortfolioComponent/MLBStats/MapComponent/mlbstats.map.component.js:39:3)↵        at eval ()↵  Evaluating http://localhost:3000/d3.js↵ Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/../public/pages/PortfolioComponent/MLBStats/MapComponent/mlbstats.map.component.js↵    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/../public/app.module.js↵   Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/../public/main.js↵ Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/../public/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution I was looking for but, removing `import * as d3 from 'd3'` and setting `declare let d3: any` above my `@Component` decorator solved the problem. I also had to add `<script src="node_modules/d3/build/d3.js"></script>` to my index.html file.